# Attraction/Repulsion Forces on objects in Three.js/Physijs

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, simulation, physics

Im working on an extra credit project for chemistry that deals with the atomic structure of a compound. Im trying to make a 3D simulation of elements around a central atom. Such as the F surrounding N in NF3.

Im trying to apply forces to the surrounding elements so that they can push eachother into the correct position in 3D space. This will be representing the atomic structure of the compund specified. Currently my simulator builds the compund but just has the surrounding elements swinging around limply in space. How can I apply a repelling force to these objects that will affect the other elements? Ive tried playing with .ApplyForce, .ApplyImpulse, etc and these seem like the correct methods to use but they are not working. Maybe I need to apply a method to the other objects to make them affected by this force?

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

`applyImpulse()` is the correct method if you want to be able to introduce spin to an object. It takes two arguments: a vector representing the force you're applying, and a vector representing the position on the object you're applying it to.

Otherwise, you want to use `applyCentralImpulse()`. As an argument it takes a vector representing the force you're applying to it.

In all cases, the vector is a 3-value vector, an instance of `THREE.Vector3`. You don't need to apply a force to two objects. That is, unless you want to model Newton's 3rd law. In other words, if you want an object to be pushed, you don't need another object doing the pushing.